# VB.net Registry DWord

Tags: vb.net, winforms, registry

I can write to the registry with no issues at all. My problem is, I am trying to add:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Excel.Sheet.8]
"BrowserFlags"=dword:80000A00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Excel.Sheet.12]
"BrowserFlags"=dword:80000A00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Excel.SheetMacroEnabled.12]
"BrowserFlags"=dword:80000A00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Excel.SheetBinaryMacroEnabled.12]
"BrowserFlags"=dword:80000A00
```

To the registry. DWord values in vb.net, when I cast them as Longs, or Decimal, say that there is a type mismatch.
The decimal value is: 2147486208. This is 10 characters long. If a remove the 8, it adds the appropriate hex value to the registry, but adding the 8 again, throws an out of range exception.

What am I doing wrong?

Edit:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim regKey As RegistryKey
    regKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\Classes\Excel.SheetMacroEnabled.12", True)
    regKey.SetValue("BrowserFlags", 2147486208, RegistryValueKind.DWord)
    regKey.Close()
End Sub
```

Returns:

```
The type of the value object did not match the specified RegistryValueKind or the object could not be properly converted.
```

Comment: *What am I doing wrong?* Asking a question like this and denying us sight of your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the constants as hex literals, like this:

```
regKey.SetValue("BrowserFlags", &H80000A00, RegistryValueKind.DWord)
```